# ModuleNotFoundError when using "openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding" ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

I'm new to Python and trying to learn how to apply GPT3's embeddings and so am following a demo. I begin by importing the following:

```
import openai
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from keys import key
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding
```

And then when I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/noahvalens/PycharmProjects/PythonGPT3Tutorial/chat.py", line 5, in <module>
    from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/embeddings_utils.py", line 4, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I already have openai and matplotlib installed with pip, so not sure what's causing this.

Another interesting fact is that, if I decide to delete the import matplotlib line from the following import list (this is found when I follow the second file link in the traceback above), it repeats the same error with each of the packages it's trying to import. This is even after I manually install each one with pip.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from scipy import spatial
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score, precision_recall_curve
from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt, wait_random_exponential
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following similar thread. You need to install openai[embeddings]

pip install openai[embeddings]

src: [OpenAI API error: "No module named 'openai.embeddings_utils'; 'openai' is not a package"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75394143/openai-api-error-no-module-named-openai-embeddings-utils-openai-is-not-a)