# OpenAI API error: "No module named 'openai.embeddings_utils'; 'openai' is not a package"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, openai-api, azure-openai

I want to use `openai.embeddings_utils import get_embeddings`
So already install openai

```
Name: openai
Version: 0.26.5
Summary: Python client library for the OpenAI API
Home-page: https://github.com/openai/openai-python
Author: OpenAI
Author-email: support@openai.com
License: 
Location: /Users/lima/Desktop/Paprika/Openai/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: aiohttp, requests, tqdm
Required-by:
```

This is my openai
But why not use openai.embeddings_utils??

Answer (score 7):

For my case, check the version of openai.
openai.embeddings_utils does not exist in latest openai 1.2.0, but exists in 0.27.7

Answer (score 4):

`openai.embeddings_utils` was removed from the library following version 1.0 (see [here](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/issues/676)).

So you have two options:

1. Install the last version of the library that included it: `pip install openai==0.28.1`.
2. Use the latest version of the library but manually incorporate methods from the `embeddings_utils` [source code](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/release-v0.28.0/openai/embeddings_utils.py) into your code.

Answer (score 4):

[@micycle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77577540/337294) shows the workarounds you can use to include the legacy `openai.embeddings_utils`. Another option is to use the new API from the latest version (Taken from [official docs](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/embeddings/what-are-embeddings)):

```
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI(api_key="YOUR_API_KEY")

def get_embedding(text, model="text-embedding-ada-002"):
   text = text.replace("\n", " ")
   return client.embeddings.create(input = [text], 
model=model).data[0].embedding

df['ada_embedding'] = df.combined.apply(lambda x: get_embedding(x, model='text-embedding-ada-002'))
```

Answer (score 2):

First run this command `pip install openai[embeddings]`.

Then import the `embeddings_utils` package lik this:
`from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding`

You can find details here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python

Comment: This method did not work for me. On installing the package `openai[embeddings]` I got a warning saying: ``WARNING: openai 1.3.6 does not provide the extra 'embeddings'``

Comment: This answer is outdated. `embeddings_utils` no longer exists in v1+.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible reasons why you get the `No module named 'openai.embeddings_utils'; 'openai' is not a package` error.

**REASON 1: Your Python code isn't correct**

Run `pip install openai` in the terminal, and then write the following in your Python script:

```
import openai
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding

# The rest of your code
```

*Note: For an example of how to use embeddings, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74000154/openai-gpt-3-api-how-do-i-make-sure-answers-are-from-a-customized-fine-tuning/75192794#75192794).*

**REASON 2: You named the file `openai.py`**

Don't name the file `openai.py`.

If you upgrade both the OpenAI Python package and Python but the error persists, then you probably named the file `openai.py`.

If you upgrade both the OpenAI Python package and Python and use the code I posted above, you should get no errors.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I don't know why pip wasn't installing some files. I solved by manually downloading [embeddings_utils.py](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/release-v0.28.0/openai/embeddings_utils.py) inside my virtual env .\venv\Lib\site-packages\openai\ folder. You might need to do the same for [datalib.py](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/main/openai/datalib.py)

Note:
if the folder is missing, openai may not be installed in the venv. To be sure you are actually installing on the virtual env, activate it and then use the command: `.\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install openai`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run this on your jupyter cell:

```
!pip install openai

import openai
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding
```

and you get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\NAVIGA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_36768/3211534756.py in <module>
      1 import openai
----> 2 from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\openai\embeddings_utils.py in <module>
      5 import plotly.express as px
      6 from scipy import spatial
----> 7 from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
      8 from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
      9 from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score, precision_recall_curve

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

then you have to :

```
!pip install scikit-learn
```

Now try:

```
import openai
from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding
```

It will run successfully

Answer (score 0):

would you like to try this? it does the job well.

```
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
```